# TypeError: gulp.hasTask is not a function в Gulp

Tags: gulp, npm, sass

Только начал изучать использование gulp и sass в вёрстке, изучаю по видеоурокам WebForMyself, ОС Windows 7, тут же столкнулся с проблемой, код которой приведён ниже.

> C:\LayoutWork\fashion>npm start
>
> > fashion@1.0.0 start C:\LayoutWork\fashion
> >     npm run build && gulp serve
> >
> > fashion@1.0.0 build C:\LayoutWork\fashion
> >     gulp build
>
> [20:04:52] Using gulpfile C:\LayoutWork\fashion\gulpfile.js [20:04:52]
>   Starting 'build'... [20:04:52] 'build' errored after 4.23 ms
>   [20:04:52] TypeError: gulp.hasTask is not a function
>       at C:\LayoutWork\fashion\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:23:22
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at verifyTaskSets (C:\LayoutWork\fashion\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js: 17:11)
>       at runSequence (C:\LayoutWork\fashion\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:130 :2)
>       at C:\LayoutWork\fashion\gulpfile.js:128:3
>       at taskWrapper (C:\LayoutWork\fashion\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.j s:13:15)
>       at bound (domain.js:415:14)
>       at runBound (domain.js:428:12)
>       at asyncRunner (C:\LayoutWork\fashion\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18 )
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! fashion@1.0.0 build: `gulp build` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the fashion@1.0.0 build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional log ging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Immortalique\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-04T17
>   _04_52_424Z-debug.log npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! fashion@1.0.0 start: `npm run build && gulp serve` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the fashion@1.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional log ging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Immortalique\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-04T17
>   _04_52_456Z-debug.log

Для полного понимания приведу ниже кусок кода из package.json и самого gulpfile.js.

Package.json -

```html
{
  "name": "fashion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "start": "npm run build && gulp serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.5",
    "del": "^4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^6.0.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^7.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile.js -

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
const imageminJpegRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');
const pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
const run = require("run-sequence");
const del = require("del");
const svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite');
const svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin');
const cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('scss/style.scss')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 version']
      }))
      .pipe(sourceMaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('*.html')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('js/**/*.js')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/**/*.css')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('allimg', function () {
  return gulp.src('img/**/*.{png,jpg}')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src('build/img/**/*.{png,jpg}')
      .pipe(imagemin([
          imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
          imageminJpegRecompress({
            loops: 5,
            min: 65,
            max: 70,
            quality: 'medium'
          }),
          imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 3}),
          pngquant({quality: '65-70', speed: 5})
      ]))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
});

gulp.task('svg', function () {
  return gulp.src('img/**/*.svg')
      .pipe(svgmin({
        js2svg: {
          pretty: true
        }
      }))
      .pipe(cheerio({
        run: function ($) {
          $('[fill]').removeAttr('fill');
          $('[stroke]').removeAttr('stroke');
          $('[style]').removeAttr('style');
        },
        parserOptions: {xmlMode: true}
      }))
      .pipe(replace('&gt;', '>'))
      // build svg sprite
      .pipe(svgSprite({
        mode: {
          symbol: {
            sprite: "sprite.svg"
          }
        }
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "build"
  });

  gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", ["sass"]);
  gulp.watch("*.html", ["html"]);
  gulp.watch("js/**/*.js", ["js"]);
  gulp.watch("css/**/*.css", ["css"]);
  gulp.watch("img/**/*.{png,jpg}", ["allimg"]);
  gulp.watch("img/**/*.{svg}", ["svg"]);
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'img/**',
      'js/**',
      'css/**',
      '*.html'
  ], {
    base: '.'
  })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('build');
});

gulp.task('build', function (fn) {
  run(
    'clean',
    'copy',
    'sass',
    'images',
    'svg',
    fn
  );
});
```

Что касается версий gulp - CLI версия 2.2.0, локальная версия 4.0.1, где-то советуют откатиться на 3.9.1, но тогда вылетает ошибка

> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined at fs.js:27:35

Дельных советов по решению проблемы полтора часа гугления не дали, так что обращаюсь за помощью сам.